# UPDATE all, except last

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
table_documents
document_id
document_folder_id
document_title
document_notify_expired

ID    FOLDER    TITLE    Notify Expired
1     2         Test1    1
2     2         Test2    1
3     2         Test3    1
4     2         Test4    1
5     2         Test5    1
```

I'm like to UPDATE and set document_notify_expired to 0 for all records EXCEPT last, for a specific folder like below

```
ID    FOLDER    TITLE    Notify Expired
1     2         Test1    0
2     2         Test2    0
3     2         Test3    0
4     2         Test4    0
5     2         Test5    1
```

Here my code but not update as expected

```
UPDATE table_documents docs
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM table_documents ORDER BY document_id DESC LIMIT 1 )last_doc ON last_doc.document_id = docs.document_id
SET doc.document_notify_expired = '0'
WHERE document_folder_id = '2'
AND last_doc.document_notify_expired = '1'
```

Comment: `UPDATE my_table SET notify_expired = 0 WHERE folder = 2; UPDATE my_table SET notify_expired = 1 WHERE folder = 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Define "last." How do you know which item is "last"? Your query will need some mechanism for identifying this, so you must have a clear definition.

Comment: On that note, if this is a one time throwaway operation and you *know* exactly which rows you want to exclude, you can just do it by ID. If this is a more general query, you *must* answer my question above.

Answer (score 4):

Try this out

```
UPDATE table_documents docs
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    MAX(id) id
FROM
    table_documents) docsmax ON docs.id != docsmax.id 
SET 
document_notify_expired = 0;
```

Obviously the last row has the greatest id, so this row is not going to be there after the join, which will returns all the other rows and you can play with them as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

```
update table1.table_documents
set table1.document_notify_expired = 0
where table1.document_folder_id = 2
    and not table1.document_id = (
        select table2.document_id
        from table_documents as table2
        where table2.document_folder_id = 2
        order by table2.document_id desc
        limit 1
    );
```

Comment: You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause